# Magento 2 payment method not showing in checkout

Tags: magento2, module, frontend, payment-methods

I have used this module in many stores https://marketplace.magento.com/ontap-module-mastercard.html.

But for some reason in a new instance of Magento that I installed, it's not showing the payment methods from this module. The payment methods are enabled, I have run these commands:

> 1- php bin/magento setup:upgrade
>
> 2- php bin/magento setup:di:compile
>
> 3- clear and flush cache
>
> 4- Reinstall the module with different versions

Nothing seems to work.
In Backend, I can see the module installed and the config options for the payment methods, but in frontend just the default Magento payment methods are shown.

Please help.
Greetings!

Answer (score 0):

if you'r running production mode try this steps worked with me :

1- switch to developer mode

```
php bin/magento deploy:mode:set developer
```

2- run these commands one bye one

```
php bin/magento setup:upgrade
php bin/magento setup:di:compile
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f
php bin/magento indexer:reindex  
php bin/magento cache:flush
php bin/magento cache:clean
```

and must be showed up

to check if you are in developer mode or production :

```
php bin/magento deploy:mode:show
```